# Wordlist generator for a specific pattern

Tags: crunch

I know my Windows machine password is `Passw0rd!`. I want to generate it using crunch so that I'd know how it works.

I tried `crunch 9 9 -t Passw@@@@`

But here `@` refers to lowercase character. I want it to be like `Passw????` where `?` can be any character. Is there a way to do it? I tried searching in many ways, I wasn't able to get it!

Answer (score 1):

The `-t` of Crunch is limited to predefined static character sets:

> `-t @,%^`
>
> Specifies a pattern, eg: `@@god@@@@` where the only the `@`'s, ,`'`s, `%`'s, and  `^`'s  will
>   change.
>
> - `@` will insert lower case characters
> - `,` will insert upper case characters
> - `%` will insert numbers
> - `^` will insert symbols

You could create own combined character sets by using the `-f`, instead.

> `-f /path/to/charset.lst charset-name`
>
> Specifies a character set from the charset.lst

Now, that doesn't work like `-t` and `-l`, but you can use it to create the suffixes. E.g. in Kali:

```
crunch 4 4 -f /usr/share/rainbowcrack/charset.txt alpha-numeric-symbol32-space -o suffix.txt
```

After that, you can use `sed` to append the prefix part (`Passw`):

```
sed -e 's/^/Passw/' suffix.txt > wordlist.txt
```

While this could be combined to a one-liner, it might be easier to understand in these two parts.